# Apache crashing while using Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db, fetchall

I have recently been studying the Zend Framework, but I have ran into a problem.

Apache crashes when I run :

```
$this->db->fetchAll("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS NumberOfUsers, COUNT(id) AS total FROM notebook")
```

But,this don't happen if I run

```
$this->db->fetchAll("SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) AS NumberOfUsers FROM notebook")
```

or

```
$this->db->fetchAll("SELECT COUNT(id) AS total FROM notebook")
```

error log :

```
---------------------------
apache.exe - Application error
---------------------------
"0x019b250a" Instruction references of "0x00000000" memory。This memory can't for "read"。
To the termination procedure, please click "ok".
Should debug program, please click "cancel".
---------------------------
ok cancel   
---------------------------
```

I don't know why this happens. Could the problem be the version of PHP I am running. (Currently I am running PHP 5.2.8). Can you help me?

Comment: First. Please don't use a lot of !!!!'s.  We don't like them.  Second.  Please edit your question so we can read it.  When you edit your question, on the right side of the page you'll see formatting guidelines.  Read them.  Follow them.  If we can't understand your question, we'll just close it.  Please format it so we can read it.

Comment: Or we could welcome the new user into the community in a positive manner by editing the question and explain how to better get his/her question answered. But, that wouldn't be the (SO) developer way. Instead, it will be down-voted to the depths of the SO database and we'll lose another community member.

Comment: apache.exe application error, "0x019b250a" "0x00000000" can not be  "read"。

Comment: @lili: you can put the error log output in the body of your question.

Comment: @JTA: I agree - I sure wish my rep were high enough to be able to help out and edit.

Comment: @dboarman Thank you very much. error log is alread add the question body.Because my English is poor,and my system is chinese,so I expain the question and error log is very difficult

Comment: Interesting. What is the database you're connecting to? MySQL? PostgeSQL? MSSQL?

Comment: @JTA It isn't too much to ask that people read the guidelines before posting. This is a rule people should get used to following on *all* sites.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the PHP version or configuration.First,checking version.Secord,checking configuration of 'php.ini',then restart apache.